# TypeError: allentry.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my allentry.map function is not working once i am updating my email and password react controlled from through with the help of react usestate hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {

    const [email,setemail ] = useState()
    const [password,setpassword ] = useState()
    const [allentry,setallentry ] = useState([])

    const submit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const newentry ={ email:email,  password: password }

        setallentry(...allentry, newentry)
    }

    return (

        <div>
        <form  onSubmit={submit} >
        
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name='email' id='email' value={email} onChange={(e)=> setemail(e.target.value) } />

            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name='password' id='password' value={password} onChange={(e)=> setpassword(e.target.value) } />

            <button type='submit' >Login</button>

        </form>
        <div>
        
        {allentry.map((person)=>{
            return (
                <h1>  {person.email} {person.password} </h1>
            )
        })
        }
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

`setallentry(...allentry, newentry)` is the problem.

The setter function returned by `useState` expects one argument, but you're giving it many. In reality, it's only using the first element in `allentry`, which is not an array and therefore does not have a `map` method.

This is what you want: `setallentry([...allentry, newentry])`

Answer (score 0):

```
{(allentry.length != 0) && 
    allentry.map((person) =>{
        return(
            <h1>  {person.email} {person.password} </h1>
        )
    })
}
```